# MongoDB replica set to stand alone backup and restore

Tags: mongodb, backup, replication, mongodump, mongorestore

For development reasons, I need to backup a production replica set mongodb and restore it on a stand alone, different machine test instance.

Some docs are talking about the opposite ( standalone 2 replica-set ), but I cannot find his downgrade/rollback way.

What's the way to go, in this case ?

Comment: Take a backup from any replica node using mongodump and restore it using mongorestore on the standalone server. It will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter how many nodes you have in a replica set, each of them holds the same data.

So getting the data is easy - just use `mongodump` (preferably against the secondary, for performance reasons) and then `mongorestore` into a new mongod for your development stand-alone system.

`mongodump` does *not* pick up any replication related collections (they live in database called `local`).  If you end up taking a file system snapshot of a replica node rather than using `mongodump`, be sure to drop the `local` database when you restore the snapshot into your production stand-alone server and then restart `mongod` so that it will properly detect that it is *not* part of a replica set.